# SSIS Script Task Error. Fill: SelectCommand.Connection property has not been initialized

Tags: c#, datatable, ssis, sqlconnection, sqldataadapter

I have been attempting this several different ways based on searches I have found online but am having the same result.

I am working on an SSIS Script Task that will execute a stored procedure that needs a TVP parameter to be passed into it. I have all that wired up and working properly, but when it gets to the `da.Fill(resultDT)`
I get the error:

> Fill: SelectCommand.Connection property has not been initialized.

```
OleDbDataAdapter A = new OleDbDataAdapter();
DataTable dt = new DataTable();

A.Fill(dt, Dts.Variables["User::Companies"].Value);

DataTable resultDT = new DataTable();

using (SqlConnection sqlcon = (SqlConnection)(Dts.Connections["RegistryConnection"].AcquireConnection(Dts.Transaction) as SqlConnection))
{
    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand())
    {
        cmd.Connection = sqlcon;
        cmd.CommandText = "[Registry].[GetClientData_ByCompanyIDs]";
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@companyIDs", dt);

        using (SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter())
        {
            da.SelectCommand = cmd;
            da.Fill(resultDT);
            Dts.Variables["User::Clients"].Value = resultDT;
        }
    }
}
```

Any ideas what I am missing? Hoping it's something easy that I am overlooking.

Comment: Okay Nevermind, the issue was the Connection Manager that I had used. I originally had this setup as OLEDB but then switched it to ADO.Net. But I never changed of the connections. Apparently the line (SqlConnection)(Dts.Connections["RegistryConnection"].AcquireConnection(Dts.Transaction) as SqlConnection) was not actually returning an SQLConnection object, and therefore not initializing the SelectCommand properly. Fixing the connection manager to be an ADO.Net connection fixed this right up!

Answer (score 0):

Issue was that I was using an OLEDB Connection Manager, which apparently cannot be cast to an SQLConnection in the way I was doing it.

Needed to setup ADO.Net Connection Manager and then the SQLConnection cast worked as intended.

Problem Solved.